# EntityFramework db.SaveChanges() Only Works When Bool is True

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

An odd thing is happening with EntityFramework.  When I debug db.SaveChanges, I can see that correct data is there, about to be sent to the database.  When the CurrentFirstName field, which is bool, is set to true, the save executes properly and the data ends up in the database.  When CurrentFirstName is set to false, nothing happens, and no data gets to the database.

The entity and stored procedures are mapped correctly.  The entity has a unique primary key.

Is it possible that somehow "false" is not getting translated to "0" correctly for the Insert Stored Procedure?  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thank you.

```
    public int PK_FirstNameID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool CurrentFirstName { get; set; }
    public int fk_DemographicsID { get; set; }

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SaveFirstName(DemographicsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            int fkid = model.fk_DemographicsID;
            int pkid = model.PK_FirstNameID;
            v_FirstNames fn = new v_FirstNames();
            fn.fk_DemographicsID = model.fk_DemographicsID;
            fn.CurrentFirstName = model.CurrentFirstName;
            fn.FirstName = model.FirstName.ToUpper();

            if (pkid > 0)
            {
                fn.PK_FirstNameID = model.PK_FirstNameID;
                unitOfWork.DemographicsFirstNamesRepository.Update(fn);
            }
            else
            {
                unitOfWork.DemographicsFirstNamesRepository.Insert(fn);
            }
            unitOfWork.Save();
            var vm = GetDemographicsViewModel(fkid);
            UpdateDocumentToDemographicsIndex(fn.fk_DemographicsID);
            if (fn.CurrentFirstName == true)
            {
                UpdateDocumentToAccessionIndex(fn.fk_DemographicsID);
            }
            return PartialView("_FirstNamesDetail", vm);
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: EF won't sent a query to the database if nothing has changed since the last save

Comment: Well, with an insert, everything has changed, correct?  It should see the data as changed.  In fact, it does for an insert with the CurrentFirstName is set to true.  It fails on an insert with the CurrentFirstName is set to false.  Am I missing something?

Comment: EF caches data so if you change something and then change it back without saving it to the db it won't send a query

Comment: Can you show the code you use to do the actual insert/update? That would help

Comment: Done.  However, I need to point out that the insert code in the controller and the store procedure are working for data with the CurrentFirstName set to true.  The update code in both the controller and stored procedure are working whenever the CurrentFirstName is set to either true or false.  Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: is it because of this if statement if (fn.CurrentFirstName == true)
            {
                UpdateDocumentToAccessionIndex(fn.fk_DemographicsID);
            }, sorry I can't be more help but that's my only suggestion

Comment: If *nothing* is inserted I suspect that the stored procedure itself screws up. If it was about misinterpreting one bit field only I'd rather expect it to do the insert, but with a wrong value.

Comment: No reggaeguitar, when I debug, the unitofwork.Save is executed, then nothing afterwards.  When I debug the UnitOfWork.cs db.SaveChanges statement, I can see that data reaches to that point, then nothing when the CurrentFirstName value is false.  It's as if EF just ignores it.

Comment: Gert, I tested the stored procedure with the same data I used in the app.  It works as expected.  So, somewhere between UnitOfWork.cs db.SaveChanges and the stored procedure, which I believe is EF, the data is being ignored or something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked the record as modified?

```
newContext.Entry(sqlEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I have the Update method marked.  Do I need to do the same with the Insert method?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I have this code in the Update method, but not in the Insert method.